# Split String Multiple Delimiters

Tags: c#, arrays, regex

I have data that I am pulling from Active Directory. I need to format the data so that it all is in the same format. The format I want is the first and last name separated by a space. This is how the data looks when I run it.

```
foreach (var item in Names)
{
string x = "Dr. Tom S. Smith";
var sName = x.Split(' ','.');

string x = "Anthony A. Kiminski";
var sName = x.Split('.');

string x = " Dr. Mike Quinn";
var sName = x.Split('.');

string x = "Seth Anderson";
}
```

The first three need to be split but the fourth one does not because it is in the correct format.

Comment: what do you want for your output? regex/split is not for natural language processing

Comment: Why not pull the data directly from AD and grab the attributes that you want: https://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/help/csv-import-management/active-directory-ldap-attributes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to use `Split`. I think you are looking for `Replace`:

```
foreach (var item in Names)
{
    string firstLast = Regex.Replace(item,"[A-Za-z]+\\.\\s","");
}
```

Comment: I was thinking split because I wanted to reformat the data. I never thought of using Regex.Replace. Should have asked the questions 4 hours ago. Thank you for your assistance